# Unable to change SupportActionBar title inside fragment

Tags: android

I have an app with a main `Activity` which hosts a `FragmentPagerAdapter`.
Inside the Activity's onCreate method I set the action bar title like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   if(getSupportActionBar() != null)
       getSupportActionBar().setTitle("test");
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Which works fine and sets the action bar title.

Now I'm trying to change the title from a `Fragment` hosted inside a `FragmentPagerAdapter` which I initialize like this inside the main `Activity`:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){

    SectionsStatePagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "Test fragment 1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(), "Test fragment 2");

    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) { }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fragment " + position);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) { }
    });
}
```

I can see that the `setTitle()` inside `onPageSelected` gets called but the title doesn't change in the Toolbar. I've also tried to do the edit inside the Fragment's `setUserVisibleHint` method like this:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getContext()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fragment 1");
```

But still the title remains the same one set inside the main Activity `onCreate`. What am I doing wrong? How can I possibly change the toolbar title from a Fragment?

Comment: Chnage to :((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Fragment 1");

Answer (score 0):

In a fragment getSupportActionBar is not accepted.

instead use

```
getActivity.getActionbar.setTitle("Name here");
```

Comment: I've tried but `getActionBar` results in a `NullPointerException`